# Convert List<dynamic> to List<T>

Tags: c#, dynamic, type-conversion

Given the following function, how do I convert from `List<dynamic> back to List<T>` ?

The line `var retval = (IEnumerable<T>)Convert.ChangeType(normalised, typeof(IEnumerable<dynamic>));`

doesn't work. The exception I get is "object must implement `IConvertible`"

```
   public static IEnumerable<T> NormalizeZeroAndOne<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        var max = list.Max();
        var min = list.Min();

        T range = ((dynamic)max - (dynamic)min);

        //var range = (max - min);
        var normalised
            = list.Select(i => ((dynamic)i - (dynamic)min) / range)
                .ToList();

        var retval = (IEnumerable<T>)Convert.ChangeType(normalised, typeof(IEnumerable<dynamic>));

        return retval;
    }
```

Comment: Try `retval = normalised.Cast<T>();`

Comment: Thanks that works.